# Can working with ArcGIS on android without ArcGIS server?

Tags: android, gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

Can I share my ArcGIS map with out ArcGIS Server?

I need to make my project for Android device and use ArcGIS to create map.

I need to use client-server in my project but I don't know how to do?

If possible can anyone please help me how to start with?

Thanks to read it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes , you can.
but its depends on project functionality, share more detail for accurate idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can publish your map directly from ArcGIS Desktop. Make use of the File >> Share As >> Service.

You need to publish a map service. You need to enable Mobile Data Access if you need any data synchronization or other advanced things

And finally you need to make use of ArcGIS Android Runtime for developing applications using the ArcGIS tools for Eclipss and build the application of your choice.

Refer to ArcGIS Resource Center for Step by Step Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use ESRI if you are trying to develop an Android Application without ArcGIS Server which means your application is not multi user.
There are bunch of opensource gis framework you can use.

However, I'll draw a path to you to follow:

First of all, If you want to use ESRI on your mobile, you'd need to buy ArcGIS Runtime license. 
Or you can use your ArcGIS Online Developer account for Lite account. See:
https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/licensing/

As @Govindran said, you can publish your map as map service and download into your mobile. But if you use GeoServer, you just paste your WMS/WFS address into your mobile app.

Comment: Well, you're completely wrong. The standard way to use ArcGIS Runtime for Android is to download a Runtime geodatase (.geodatase) from ArcgisOnline or Portal, and edit the file completely offline, and then synchronize again, and commit the changes. So much for your multi-user scenario. Alternatively it's possible to generate a runtime geodatase or a Mobile map package (. Mmpk) with ArcGIS Pro and transfer the file to Android device in order to be edited.

Comment: Well, you are not completely wrong. There was no ArcGIS Online or Portal before. We were using RUD key instead of them. Using AGOL or Portal is another, new case. You don't have to follow them. But if I want to use my portal yes you are right. But as you see on the question, there is no mention about Portal or AGOL. And your alternative way had been said. You can contact with your local ESRI distribution.